# unity3d how to change color of instantiated prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors

In unity, I have a prefab, and I want to instantiate it and change colors of instantiated prefabs to black. The prefab's default color is yellow. My goal is to change color to random color, but now it's just black.
 I'll make random colors later. But there is a problem: the color doesn't change. I've checked some solutions fount on the internet, but none of them works for me.
Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class starsGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

public float square_size;
public int stars_in_square;
public int galaxy_size;
public Transform star;


void generateGalaxy() {
    float rootSquareX = -(square_size/2.0f);
    float rootSquareY = (square_size/2.0f);



    for(int i = 0; i < galaxy_size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < galaxy_size; j++)
        {
            Color color = Color.black;

            float sqx = rootSquareX + (i * square_size);
            float sqy = rootSquareY + (j * square_size);

            for(int k = 1; k <= stars_in_square; k++)
            {
                float strx = Random.Range(sqx + 0.2f, sqx + square_size - 0.2f);
                float stry = Random.Range(sqy + 0.2f, sqy + square_size - 0.2f);

                Color newColor = new Color(Random.value, Random.value, Random.value, 1.0f);


                Transform instd = Instantiate(star, new Vector3(strx, stry, 4.44f), Quaternion.identity);

                instd.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
                // also instd.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = color; doesn't work
            }
        }
    }
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    generateGalaxy();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

}
```

And my prefab:
[image: this is my prefab]

**EDIT**:
Please note that my prefab doesn't use default shader. Is this a problem?

This is prefab's shader:

```
Shader "Custom/GlowShader" 
{
 Properties 
 {
  _ColorTint("Color Tint", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
  _MainTex("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
  _BumpMap("Normal Map", 2D) = "bump" {}
  _RimColor("Rim Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
  _RimPower("Rim Power", Range(1.0, 6.0)) = 3.0

 }
 SubShader {

  Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }

  CGPROGRAM
  #pragma surface surf Lambert

  struct Input {

   float4 color : Color;
   float2 uv_MainTex;
   float2 uv_BumpMap;
   float3 viewDir;

  };

  float4 _ColorTint;
  sampler2D _MainTex;
  sampler2D _BumpMap;
  float4 _RimColor;
  float _RimPower;

  void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) 
  {


   IN.color = _ColorTint;
   o.Albedo = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex).rgb * IN.color;
   o.Normal = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_BumpMap,IN.uv_BumpMap));

   half rim = 1.0 - saturate(dot(normalize(IN.viewDir), o.Normal));
   o.Emission = _RimColor.rgb * pow(rim, _RimPower);


  }
  ENDCG
 } 
 FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the color through the renderer

```
    GameObject go = Instantiate(_ShieldPrefab);
    Renderer rend = go.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    rend.material.color = Color.black;
```

Or alternatively change the material.

```
    GameObject go = Instantiate(thePrefabYouInstantiate);
    Renderer rend = go.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    rend.material = yourNewMaterial;
```

What I mean is. Make 2 materials, one that is yellow, one that is black. Then use the 2nd alternative solution I provided as code to change the material during runtime. Just instead of where I wrote "yourNewMaterial" it should be the name of your material variable for the black material.

It shouldn't be a problem that you don't use the default shader.

Comment: I tested it in a project of my own before I posted it. Worked fine there.

Can you post the inspector view of your object as a picture?

Try with a normal shader temporarily as well, just to see if that works.

Comment: It works with standard shader. I've posted my shader's code here. I don't know much about shaders, this one is taken from internet. Is there any way to fix it? I need to use this shader.

Comment: Could try the material switch instead, where you change the material and then just in your assets have one that looks black?

Comment: If I change color in assets, the color of prefab will also change. But I need to change it at runtime.

Comment: What I mean is. Make 2 materials, one that is yellow, one that is black. Then use the 2nd alternative solution I provided as code to change the material during runtime. Just instead of where I wrote "yourNewMaterial" it should be the name of your material variable for the black material.

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thank you. (Write it in your answer, so I can upvote and accept)