# How to change color of the instance of a prefab in runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have a problem to change of color of prefab object in runtime.

The problem is that the prefab is composed of a GameObject and inside it is the cube. Therefore, when you instance the object from runtime does not allow you to change the color. How can I identify that created object and change its color or any other property?

Here the image of the error:

[image: Errors]

This is my repository with the project (branch develop): https://github.com/emicalvacho/MapaMentalAR

Comment: Please show your code .. we don't want to search your repository for any applicable code snippet

Comment: Please provide Code as your Repo project is empty. If i had to take a guess you have a reference in your script to the prefab and you are trying to change it's color after you instantiate it but you are still changing the prefab. When you do Instantiate do it as GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefabRef);
        obj.ChangeColor();

Comment: Where are all these scripts `PaintScript, ActiveScript, SelectScript, .....` attached to? You might want to rethink your hierarchy structure  .. and check what you referenced every where in the `obj` field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unity3d how to change color of instantiated prefab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844379/unity3d-how-to-change-color-of-instantiated-prefab)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Therefore, when you instance the object from runtime does not allow you to change the color

Yes .. simply store the reference when you instantiate. From your exception in the console you can see that you (accidently?) are trying to change the color of the prefab itself - not the just created instance.

```
var instance = Instantiate(prefab, position, rotation);
var objRenderer = instance.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>(true);
objRenderer.material.color = Color.blue;
```

It seems that in your scripts you are referencing the prefab instead of the instantiated object.

Answer (score 0):

After creating a game object at runtime you can not access it's properties directly
if you want to change color of cube that created runtime first of all you need to get a component named meshRenderer then you can pick the material of that meshRenderer ander getting a material you can change the color of it.

```
GameObject obj  = Instantiate(cubePrefab, position, rotation));
obj.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply you cant.
Either you have seperate Prefabs with the different colors, or you change the material after you instanced it to the desired color.